# Swap error balancer.exchange

Tags: balances, swaps

I am using balancer.exchange to swap Dai for xHDX.

It says the swap was successful but did not swap. I still have my Dai and did not get the xHDX.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x07a43b7fca5eec146566dfc7f3a983bb6ccbc28925c2098837915d4aaf4b0fe8

Not sure what to do to fix this? Or did I just loose the ETH Gas fee and the swap messed up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction you posted is an Approval transaction, it is not a Swap transaction.  You just gave permission to ExchangeProxy contract to run your trades. That's all you did.
Nothing to fix. Now you can send a swap transaction.

Comment: Oh. Interesting. I am used to uniswap which just swaps all in one go. Thank you for the insight.